# how to know when a website is static or dynamic

Tags: html, reactjs

Is a web page that is automatically querying an api every 30 seconds,

1. Without any user interaction, a static or dynamic web page?
2. If it is a static website is it ok to use reactjs or would it be good to use nextjs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to me .. if you don't update the content of your web page.. Then it's static. But if your content is changed according to user/product/region then it will be dynamic webpage.

For example in static we can consider web1.0 website where data is changed manually and no action is performed. But in web 2.0 data changed and even received from backend with different logic.

So this is the difference between static and dynamic.

Now move on your question-

1. You can use useEffect() function of ReactJs where you can set an array of time. That will fetch data from time to time.
2. either a static or dynamic i advice you to use ReactJs.(Personal Opinion)

Hope you like the answer if you still face any problem, just lemme know.
Thanks